# How to setup WSS Websockets on AWS EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, amazon-ecs

I am fairly new to AWS and I'm setting up an app on AWS that uses WebSockets.
I have an ECS Cluster sitting on an EC2 Instance in AWS. I can externally ping my instance and I can connect to it via plain ws:// however, I cannot connect to it through wss://.
I have allowed All Traffic (Plus all TCP) from Anywhere on my Security Group and Network ACL.
I have also set up an SSL certificate and set up an A record to point the domain to my instances public IP address in Route 53.
I had read a bit about load balancers and I've tried setting one up to get it working however this didn't work either.
Is there any way to achieve this without a Load Balancer?

I know I am probably missing something simple, however, I can't find any straight forward information on setting up wss:// on AWS.

If anyone could walk me through the steps or point me to some applicable instructions that would be greatly appreciated!

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks

Here are my Security Group Rules:
[image: Security Group Inbound Rules]

Comment: Did you check whether you ECS tasks supports wss? The best way to set it up is with a loadbalancer you can do ssl termination from your elb meaning that elb and ecs tasks comunicate via ws it offers more performance boost in long term.

Comment: How can I check the wss support on the task? I can connect to my tasks through ws:// just not wss.
Okay, and is an Application Load Balancer the one to choose for this sort of application?
Thanks for the comment

Comment: Ever figure this out?